# webretc video activity , puting local video view on front layout

Tags: android, webrtc

I m developping webrtc android application, I used Relative layout to put in it two SurfaceViewRenderer elements one used for local stream view  and other for remote stream.

here my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/video_layout"    
>       
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"        
 >

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/glview_parent"    
    >  

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
    android:id="@+id/remoteview"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/localview"
    /> 

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
    android:id="@+id/localview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />

   </RelativeLayout>  


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageTXT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:paddingTop="50dp"   
    android:paddingRight="50dp"     
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#66000000"
    android:textColor="@color/list_background"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />


   <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronoLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:paddingTop="50dp"   
    android:paddingRight="50dp"     
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#66000000"
    android:textColor="@color/list_background"
    android:visibility="gone"/>



   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#66000000"
    >  

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/speaker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/speaker_on" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"  
        android:paddingRight="10dp"               
      /> 
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ok01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ok" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"             
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" 
      /> 

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" 
        /> 

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/micro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:src="@drawable/mico_on"                     
        /> 
   </LinearLayout>         




 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

on call progressing i initialised local and remote  SurfaceViewRenderer programetically like this .

```
public void initVideos() {   
          remotevideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams local,remote;
          remote=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);              
          remotevideoview.setLayoutParams(remote); 
          local =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);              
          localvideoView.setLayoutParams(local);  
        }
```

When call is establiched and onaddstream event fire I update layout like this :

```
public void updateVideos(){              
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams remote =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);              
          int w=video_layout.getWidth();
          int h=video_layout.getHeight();
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams local = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w/3, h/3); // or wrap_content
          local.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
          local.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
          local.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);              
          glview_parent.updateViewLayout(remotevideoview, remote);
          glview_parent.updateViewLayout(localvideoView, local);
          remotevideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          localvideoView.bringToFront();
          glview_parent.invalidate();
          localvideoView.invalidate();
          remotevideoview.invalidate();

        }
```

All is ok until now. but when i click onbackpressed and exit call activity. and after that I like to show local and remote videos again when user enter on call activity. I call  updateVideos() and i render local and remote stream but I can not see  localvideoView. I see only remotevideoview that match all parent width and height. localvideoview is always bring to back . I try all possible codes but I can not see localview. I use localvideoView.bringToFront(); but without success.

Comment: resolved with : localvideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);